# Rollback changes when code not executed properly

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to SQL, In my project I am trying to fill the DataSet from the DataBase table and then inserting new rows in DataSet. After doing this, again I am filling the Database table with the DataSet data. Before filling I am clearing or deleting the Database table data. Well I achieved this by using the below code:

```
Database Table --> myTable
DataSet --> ds
```

---

**OnButtonClick**

```
   string strQuery = "delete from [dbo].[myTable]"
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
   SqlCommand command;
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   using (cmd)
   {
      using (conn)
      {
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    //deleting database table data
         foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) //Inserting new data into the Database table
         {
             command = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, conn);
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         conn.Close();
      }
   }
```

The above code is working fine but when there is any exception in `command` sqlCommand then it is deleting the database table completely and not filling the DataSet. Any suggestions to modify this code? please help.

UPDATE:

```
            string strQuery = "delete from [dbo].[myTable]";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdReset = new SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('myTable', RESEED, 0)", conn))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                    cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                   //deleting database table data
                        cmdReset.ExecuteNonQuery();               //Resetting Identity of first column
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) //Inserting new data into the Database table
                        {
                            command = new SqlCommand(query.createDoctorRow(InsertQuery, conn);
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        sqlTransaction.Commit();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        sqlTransaction.Rollback();
         /*ERROR*/      throw;  
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

> ERROR -->  "ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized."

Comment: Do please consider a more descriptive title to your question. It should be a brief summary of your problem. =)

Comment: ya I am thinking but still confused what to keep. sorry.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. I am new to SQL. please dont say any SQL things I want to do this using c# as far as possible

Comment: Could you say what do you want to achieve using this? Why do you delete all previous rows? Is this rows doublicates in your new rows in dataset?

Comment: I thought doing this will make my code small. I am having this last trouble with my project (I think).

Comment: @Mr_Green Without using SQL features your C# code that handles everything in proper way will be much larger than using SQL features, because basically you'll have to write your own SQL server.

Comment: Depending on the size of the application you might wish to use an ORM to abstract the use of SQL and avoid it *almost* completely, but this getting off the topic of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a transaction to run the sql

```
string strQuery = "delete from [dbo].[myTable]";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
  using (cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn))
  {
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     conn.Open();
     SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
     cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
     try
     {
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    //deleting database table data
         foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) //Inserting new data into the Database table
         {
             command = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, conn);
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         sqlTransaction.Commit();
         conn.Close();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         sqlTransaction.Rollback();
         throw;
     }
  }
```

}

Transactions form an all or nothing scenario. Either everything in the transaction works and is committed to the database, or the whole lot is cancelled as if nothing happened.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. I am new to SQL. please dont say any SQL things I want to do this using c# as far as possible

Comment: This is C#.  If you are going to use SQL, you need to learn "SQL things."

Comment: I am trying your code but it is not committing let me check again.

Comment: @Mr_Green reading through it again I did misname a couple of variables, which I've now corrected.

Comment: ERROR -- `Invalid operation. The connection is closed.` at `SqlTransaction sqlTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();`

Comment: @Mr_Green oops! move the line creating the transaction after the opening of the connection

Comment: @JamesB sorry for late response.. please check my update. I have done what you said but it is showing error which I mentioned in my update section of question.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your efforts. I was missing the transaction parameter for instances of SqlCommands.

Answer (score 3):

This [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) has a nice way of wrapping sql commands in a transaction scope. Basically if any exception is thrown during any of the row insert the delete query will fail as well.

In a nut shell you wrap everything inside a

```
 using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
            {
                 //enter your code here
            }
      }
```

Also you don't have to do an insert row by row you can use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to do it more efficiently.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
         {                               
                  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;
                  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
         }
  }
```